# How to get SelectedValue of DropdownList without postback or updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `DropDownList` which i am binding on page load. i dont have any buttons or anything. as soon as user selects the value in dropdown i need to show that value in label. i am not sure why this is not working. please help.

```
public string SelectedStore { get; set; }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
          BindStoresList();
      }
}
 protected void BindStoresList()
 {  storeDDList.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
    storeDDList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select store", "-1"));
    TempCollection stores = TempDataSource.LoadForCriteria("ALL", "Code ASC");
    storeDDList.DataSource = stores;
    storeDDList.DataTextField = "DisplayName";
    storeDDList.DataValueField = "Code";
   storeDDList.DataBind();
 }
  protected void storeDDList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     SelectedStore = storeDDList.SelectedValue.ToString();
     selectedItem.Text = SelectedStore;
   }
```

I dont need any kind of jquery stuff as i am going to add gridview which binds depending on the value of dropdown..

```
****** EDITS *******
```

if i set `AutoPostBack=True`  then on page refresh my DropDownList doesn't bind at all as you can see in Page_Load Method, it will not call `BindStoresList()` method.

```
***** ANSWER *****
```

For people who might get stuck with this..

i was setting the `EnableViewState` to `True` for the `DropDownList`, so after page refreshes the `SelectedValue` was getting lost. after removing the `EnableviewState` and setting `AutoPostBack` to `Ture` working fine...

Comment: setting AutoPostBack=True on dropdownlist will result in a server post back and will trigger the event storeDDList_SelectedIndexChanged. So whenever you will change the selected index of dropdonwlist storeDDList_SelectedIndexChanged event will be triggered server side and your code inside this event will be called.

Comment: i tried this one and after page refresh, DropDownList doesnot bind#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `AutoPostBack=True` for the dropdown, it will automatically send the call to server side without need to extra button.

Comment: You do not need to bind it again, binding it again will remove the selector from the dropdown.

Comment: i tried what you said. Setting AutoPostBack = True and it seems that after page refresh DropDownList does not bind at all.

Comment: Put a break point in on select index change and see where the code goes after

Comment: I got it... your solution worked for me .. the error was i was setting EnableViewstate = false, which caused the value to lost after postback..

Answer (score 6):

You can Use `JavaScript` . Set the `OnChange` attribute for your DropDownList to call a JS function and Change your label text there:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
          BindStoresList();
          storeDDList.Attributes["onChange"] = "ChangeLabelText();";
      }
}
```

`JS` function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeLabelText() {

     var lbl = document.getElementById("<%=lbl.ClientID%>");
     var ddl = document.getElementById("<%=ddl.ClientID%>");

     lbl.innerHTML = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: this is correct... BUT i specifically mentioned in my post that i do not need any kind of javascript or jquery solution...

Answer (score 1):

You may do it using Javascript, handle the OnChange event of the DropDownList and set the text of the label you want

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" onchange="ddl_change(this.value)"/>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ddl_change(value)
{
var lbl = document.getElementById('<%= yourlabel.ClientID %>');
lbl.value = value;
}
</script>
```

Good luck.